# array_replace_recursive(): Argument #2 must be of type array, int given form validation

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel form validation, I created a request named "CreateEntrepriseForm" which validates my form, everything works perfectly. My application is multi language  and the default language is English and my problem is when I change it to French I receive the error message above in my middleware class which allows me to change the language.
I would like my form to work for all languages.
Thanks in advance.

**Here is my CreateEntrepriseForm class which validates my form** :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateEntrepriseForm extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            //
            'name_entreprise' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            //
            'name_entreprise.required' => __('main.enter_your_company_name_please'),
        ];
    }
}
```

**My function in the controller who receive request data :**

```
public function saveEntreprise(CreateEntrepriseForm $requestF)
{
     $name_entreprise = $requestF->input('name_entreprise');

     dd($name_entreprise);
}
```

**My middleware which allows me to change languages ​​named Language :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class Language
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if(Session()->has('applocale') AND array_key_exists(Session()->get('applocale'), config('languages')))
        {
            App::setLocale(Session()->get('applocale'));
        }
        else
        {
            App::setLocale(config('app.fallback_locale'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Here is the error capture :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, I just had to add the validator.php file to my languages ​​folder.

THANKS